# Numix-icon size problem in the top-bar

Tags: themes, icons

I have installed numix-icon-theme but it seems broken and weird. As you can see in the image, the topbar icons are way huge compare to normal. How do i fix this?

[image]

Another help i'm asking for y'all is how can i change the "Applications" to windows-like orb(like a mac-logo).

Comment: That's the normal size of the icon I think.